# Monitor constantly flickering between no signal

Tags: windows-7, display, hardware-failure, amd-radeon

Info -
Gfx Card: 7850
TV: Element 55 inch
OS: windows 7 64 bit

I'm using 1080p/HDMI.

When I turn my computer on, I get 'no signal' all the way until the log in screen, because apparently the BIOS/start up routine isn't being displayed in 1080p, but that doesn't seem right.  When I first got my computer, I had no problem setting stuff up in the BIOS screen.

Now, when I start my computer from being 'asleep', it constantly flashes to 'no signal' for about 5 minutes and then it stops and never does it again the entire time I'm using it (until I put it to sleep again).

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I feel like my TV might have faulty HDMI ports, but I'm not sure.  When I play games, any time the resolution goes below 1920x1080, I get 'no signal'.  Some example of games: The Sims 3 and Wizardry Online. I can't even play them and the only way I can get my display back is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until I'm on my desktop.

Comment: Have you checked the cables or tried different ones?

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling/reinstalling ATI drivers from http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

There's often a BIOS option for selecting a default display adapter. May want to make sure that is set correctly along with the various power settings.

Comment: im using a radeon hd 7870 lol

Comment: oops, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have blown capacitors in your monitor. Flashing screens can be a symptom of that. I would recommend you try software fixes before opening up your monitor though.